# get values from json object list

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json format.

```
{  
"cod":"200",
"message":0.0027,
"cnt":40,
"list":[  
       {  
       "dt":1510045200,
       "main":{  
              "temp":281.46
              }
       },
       {
       "dt":....
       ....
       }
       ]
}
```

Using javascript and ajax request, I am trying to get the value of dt and temp from each object in data.list but with no result..

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            //number of objects in data.list array
            var numOfObjects = data.list.length; 
            for (var i = 0; i < numOfObjects; i++){
                if(data.list[i].hasOwnProperty('td')){
                    console.log(data.list[i].['td']);
                }
                else if(data.list[i].['main'].hasOwnProperty('temp')){
                    console.log(data.list[i].['main'].['temp']);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You search for `td` in your code instead of `dt` . `console.log(data.list[i].['td']);` also contains an extra dot.

Comment: Replace `td` with `dt` in your code: `if(data.list[i].hasOwnProperty('dt'))..` And you should be good to go

Comment: @Harman after removing extra dots that is

Comment: @mplungjan Yes agree

Comment: you have mistake in your code. You are using td instead of dt. to access a value use data.list[i].td or data.list[i]['dt'] the dot between [i] and ['dt'] is wrong syntax.

Comment: thanks. I didnt notice itt

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put a `.` between array keys :

For example : `data.list[i].['dt']` is incorrect, `data.list[i]['dt']` is correct.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        //number of objects in data.list array
        var numOfObjects = data.list.length; 
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfObjects; i++){
            if(data.list[i].hasOwnProperty('dt')){
                console.log(data.list[i]['dt']);
            }
            else if(data.list[i]['main'].hasOwnProperty('temp')){
                console.log(data.list[i]['main']['temp']);
            }
        }
    }
});
```